# Loss of feature names when onehotencoding

Tags: python, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

Building pipelines with onehotencoding and when fitting and transforming to training/test set and converting into data frame it results in the features not having names. Is there any way to get names for each encoded feature?

```
# Numerical column transformer
num_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

# Categorical column transformer
cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

# Preprocessing pipeline
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', cat_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])


# Fitting the data and transforming the training & test set
X_train_preprocessed = preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train)
test_preprocessed = preprocessor.fit_transform(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access transformers using attribute [`named_transformers_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.named_transformers_) of `ColumnTransformer`. You have 2 transformers named `'num'` and `'cat'`, so `preprocessor.named_transformers_['cat']` gives you access to your `cat_transformer`. Then using [`named_steps`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn-pipeline-pipeline) attribute of `Pipeline` you can access your `OneHotEncoder` named `'onehot'` and its `categories_` attribute:

```
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]

preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
Out[6]: 
array([[-1.22474487,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.22474487,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ]])

preprocessor.named_transformers_['cat'].named_steps['onehot'].categories_
Out[7]: [array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object)]
```